# Should funny comments (100% joke) be considered as not constructive?

Tags: discussion, comments, up-votes

Sometimes funny comments contain information, **so they are totally helpful** and constructive. But I have seen many funny comments that **have no added value!**

**Edit:**
Why do 100% funny comments get so many upvotes? Note that the upvote tooltip states that *"this comment adds something useful to the post"*.

Is a comment that is only meant to be funny "not constructive"?

**Notes:**
Personally, I don't think there should be any policy about such comments, and any comment is fine while it's not offensive.

Comment: Meta is a little more flexible, but you are right I suppose. Down with fun!

Comment: I'm guessing here but I expect they thought; "You thought it wasn't constructive, you flagged it as not constructive, a moderator agreed it wasn't constructive, it was deleted as not constructive, wheres the issue?"

Comment: "*Why did this comment got 8 upvotes?*" <-- because them users be crazy! No but seriously, it is kind of a commentary on the seemingly random, irrational and contradictory behaviors of the users to similar questions, and that there's no good explanation for those behaviors. As long as things don't get out of hand, I don't mind a funny comment or two. Live and let live.

Comment: Honestly I'm *really* tired of people complaining about funny comments.  It's a comment! "Not constructive" was chosen as the politically correct way to say, *"Tears people down, destroys the community rather than builds it up"* It was never meant to be the cudgel users grab whenever they see something that isn't particularly useful to them.

Comment: I commented why I downvoted. Who deleted it?

Answer (score 24):

> Why did this comment got 8 upvotes?

Because 8 people agreed enough with the commenter to click a little arrow that appears when hovering over the comment.

> Should it be even allowed?

"Allowed" is a very strong word; an overly strong word. If I wrote such a comment what would my punishment be? Let's assume you're asking whether Stack Exchange should have a policy that such comments should be deleted instead. That's possible; I <sup>1</sup> would consider it excessive.

> Does 100% funny --> not constructive?

Probably, yes. As long as the commenter isn't being offensive I really don't see what the problem is. Stack Exchange is not going to be able to regulate absolutely everything that happens on the network. If enough people are occasionally not 100% on-topic then there's not much that anyone can do about it.

If you feel strongly about it then by all means flag the comment and the comment may be deleted, depending on the mood of the moderator at the time. Trying to stem the tide, especially on Meta, would probably be futile. YMMV.

Remember; [we hate fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

<sub>1. That's me; I don't speak for any other person or company.</sub>

Comment: Flags on such a comment will be handled/dismissed on the discretion of the moderator. Remember, lots of users flagging a comment will cause it to be auto deleted. If a comment is just funny and neither rude or misleading I don't see a big need to intervene with mod powers - if the *community* disliked it enough people would flag it to trigger auto-deletion.

Answer (score 12):

> Should funny comments (100% joke) be considered as not constructive?

The comment you referenced is "arguably" non-constructive, but was a little fun, wasn't offensive, and you can just ignore it and read the comments which were constructive even if not useful.
If enough people flagged against it auto removal would have occurred, otherwise ignore it.

While this is frowned upon in SO, and isn't *really* allowed here, people turn a blind eye here as questions on meta carry a certain element of discussion. Discussions by nature carry a certain element of personal opinion, and that brings about the odd wise crack (my hands are up I'm guilty too..).

As for all "funny" comments, sometimes it's hard on face value to know exactly what someone meant in a comment.
Sure sometimes it's obvious so just remove, but not always, and that can bring lots of time spent deliberating, discussing and possibly even more comments and new questions to debate and ask why it was removed...etc.

As an example, take "Because users be crazy! CRAZY I tell you!", it's seen as non-constructive on face value, I do see your argument, but if you're sat hovering over the "delete comment button" because you feel it's non-constructive, to remain unbiased you also have to consider it could be translated to "Some people are just like that and do stupid things and so vote willy nilly"...
...And therefore potentially constructive!

I'm not outright debating this particular comment was constructive or otherwise, just that it's hard to decide.

You also have to consider that if all things meta were to become only permissible if "constructive", your question here could arguably also be deemed as removable in the argument that you have no issue - because the comment was reported and removed.
Again, the debate of what should be removed and who decides....

A *bit* of light humour *occasionally* in the mix is welcomed imo.
I've always enjoyed working environments where my colleagues are professional, and can have a laugh now and then but at the same time continue to do work professionally.
I feel it's like that here.

> Sometimes funny comments contain information, so it's totally helpful and constructive. But I have seen many funny comments that have no added value!

I don't think one can dictate that if a comment is funny and constructive it's ok, but if it's funny only then it's not.
IMO it's either turn a blind eye and allow a small amount of fun, or not at all.