# Why are funny but massively upvoted comments removed?

Tags: discussion, comments, fun

Based on the responses on the question [Should funny comments (100% joke) be considered as not constructive?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197763/should-funny-comments-100-joke-be-considered-as-not-constructive), it seems that funny comments are welcomed, or at least tolerated on SO, as long as they are not offensive.

So why are comments with a hundred of upvotes being removed?

One example I witnessed today (and it led me to ask this question) was on [Working copy XXX locked and cleanup failed in SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127932/working-copy-xxx-locked-and-cleanup-failed-in-svn), on which two funny comment were removed:

> .6. Fight depression – Yannis May 22 '10 at 4:11  (91 upvotes)
>
> .7. Switch to GIT or HG – Skylar Saveland Jun 11 '10 at 19:15 (114 upvotes)

(Snapshot of the question [available on web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20130822152733/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127932/working-copy-xxx-locked-and-cleanup-failed-in-svn))

The second is even (a little) constructive by proposing alternatives to the tool OP is using. So why are these removed?

Comment: Are the acceptable? Sure.  Are the guaranteed to last forever?  No.  Most of the time, they are just noise that don't offer much to the post, so they can get deleted if a mod cleans up the comments on that post.

Comment: Because StackOverflow is a Question and Answer site, not a Question, Answer and Commenting site.

Comment: OTOH, is SO a site for robots or humans? If it's for humans, then it should not be the goal to obliterate any signs of human interaction that *"does not contribute to the answer"*. These comments do contribute to perception of community as a community of human beings.

Comment: Comments help out at the time the question / answer has been posted, as a way of prompting the poster to give more details or to expand on things. That is the human element. However they don't really serve a purpose if they still exist 4 years after being left.

Comment: Nothing funny about that first comment...

Comment: There's nothing constructive about "Switch to GIT or HG." We are all aware of git and Hg. We're not all working on personal projects all the time where we can choose whatever tools we like.

Comment: @JonW - If useful comments were edited into the question or answer to which they are attached, that would be true.  However, on SO, many comments contain useful information which is not present in the question or answer.  Whatever the intent of comments, in practice they have usefulness beyond the ephemeral.

Comment: @WayneConrad But this post isn't saying that useful, constructive, and on topic comments are being removed, merely that offtopic, entertaining, and unconstructive comments are being removed.  That's a very different matter.

Comment: If content is deemed as useful but is only in a comment then really it should be a) added into the post itself, b) turned into a separate answer in its own right.

Comment: @JonW Sometimes questions and/or answers aren't relevant after 4 years, either. So why not delete those too?

Comment: @IanKemp If answers are wrong or useless after a while then they often are deleted. However good questions will get answers that don't suddenly become wrong / useless (which is why 'Which X is the best' type questions don't work - answers get out of date on those, if there even could be a correct answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Comments are second class citizens.

Comments can be happy that they are allowed to live with us here at all!

On a more serious note, comments are considered *temporary*, they're not meant to hold anything of value and are there to address points in the question, request clarification or similar. Multiple times it was clearly said that comments can be deleted without warning or second thought.

### Upvotes are not a valid metric for "right", "valid" or "on topic".

> So why are comments with a hundred of upvotes being removed?

Why are questions with hundreds of upvotes removed? Why are answers with hundreds of upvotes removed? Because upvotes does not make them right!

Votes, up and down, are no valid metric for considering how on-topic, well formed or useful a post is. That applies to questions, answers and especially comments. Comments receive more upvotes than answers (and answers more than questions), that's because of their nature, they don't yield reputation and can be considered "unimportant".

### The more time goes by the more users see it.

One phenomenon is that the more time goes by, the more users see something, the more likely it is to get flagged. Most likely were both comments removed after receiving a flag from someone who considered them completely misplaced. And that's totally fine, they're second class citizens and subject to deletion.

### So, is fun allowed?

My favorite answer: It depends.

We hate fun on Stack Overflow, but comments are a special case. But don't expect them to last.

Comment: "Comments are second class citizens, and it's just a fact of life for them that we come along occasionally and, y'know, kill them."

Answer (score 10):

Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers (https://stackoverflow.com/about). Its all about what the users come here for: answers for their questions. Comments are just a tool to help the professionals who are around to understand questions and give more focused answers. If a comment contributes to the answer, just convert it or append to the suitable existing answer.

So, long story short: answers are persistent, comments are temporary.

Comment: side notice: this is the Stack Exchange network meta site, so this argument should consider **all** the sites and not just Stack Overflow. If this was pertinent only to Stack Overflow, it should go on the site specific meta. Other than this, the answer is (sadly) correct - comments are temporary and all the system is built so that people won't notice their removal